# reloadData in AppDelegate Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have a function in my AppDelegate which is similar to, DidReceiveRemoteNotification, and upon receiving a message appends a message to an array and then attempts to reload a tableview.

My app consists of just one Viewcontroller and one AppDelegate.

My code looks like this:

```
    var myCustomViewController: ViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    println("******didReceiveMessage*****")
    myCustomViewController.messages.append(message.data.message as! String)
    println(myCustomViewController.messages)
    myCustomViewController.MessageTableView.reloadData()
```

whenever I try to call a reload function my app crashes however. Is there a way to reload my tableView from my appDelegate function?

Comment: what the crash message says ?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: myCustomViewController.MessageTableView.reloadData()

Comment: check if .MessageTableView is not nil

Comment: Yea it apparently is nil. but it shouldn't be?

Comment: no, it shouldn't. Is MessageTableView an outlet to a tableview ? Check if outlet is connected

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var MessageTableView: UITableView!
is connected OK

Comment: Change to strong or use  ViewController() to init your view controller

Comment: changing to strong didnt fix it. Not sure what you mean but I will try using ViewController() to init my view controller

Comment: var myCustomViewController = ViewController();

Comment: add this into my appDel or ViewController?

Comment: replace with   var myCustomViewController: ViewController = ViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

Comment: Didnt fix it for me ... :(

Answer (score 1):

Your view isn't loaded yet, so the table view doesn't exist yet, hence it is nil.

It isn't clear whether you're using the correct view controller, because you're creating a new one. Either call `view` on it to create the view (and subviews) or change the reference to the real existing view controller.

Most likely you should be accessing the root view controller of the app delegates `window`.